# Setup reliable `preLaunchTask` for running server when debugging create-react-app

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

**Goal**

I would like to setup VSCode debugging for a create-react-app with Typescript. A couple years ago I used to work with Visual Studio 20XX and the debugging experience there was great, because you would not need to leave your IDE. I have been trying to replicate something similar every once in a while when I switched over to the Node ecosystem and Visual Studio Code, but I just haven't been able to succeed. Each method I have implemented either does not work reliably, or seems a bit cumbersome.

Ideally I would be able to press a single button resulting in an opened tab with the app in question.

**Context**

The project we are working on both has developers using Windows and OSX. A variety of browsers is used for local debugging, but it would be perfectly fine if a single browser is selected by VSCode. For this question I will focus on OSX, but ideally I would like to set it up for Windows as well.

**Steps Taken**

The VSCode documentation states that there are two different methods for debugging. Launching and attaching ([here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-versus-attach-configurations) and [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/browser-debugging#_launching-browsers)).

**Launching**

Originally it seemed like launching was the most in line with what I was after. This is the initial `launch.json` file that I setup with the documentation.

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

While this worked, it opens a separate instance of Chrome or Brave (without browse history etc). Additionally, you still need to run `npm run start` and with create-react-app that opens a tab in your current browser instance. Theoretically the opening of the tab can be prevented, but this hinders a workflow that is already is used. So I would need to setup another start script.

This already feels a bit janky. Not only does a dev need to be aware of this all, but I think these will be barriers in its adoption.

**Add preLaunchTask**
Therefore I decided to explore adding a `preLaunchTask` to this config. Unfortunately, I was not able to get this to work reliably.

```
    "start:v3": "export REACT_APP_OVERRIDE_VERSION=v3|| set REACT_APP_OVERRIDE_VERSION=v3&& npm start react-scripts start",
    "start:v3:background": "export BROWSER='none'|| set BROWSER='none'&& npm run start:v3",
```

`launch.json`

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      // Same as above
      "preLaunchTask": "npm: start:v3:background"
    }
  ]
}
```

`tasks.json`

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "start:v3:background",
      "group": {
        "kind": "test",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "isBackground": true,
      "problemMatcher": [
        {
          "pattern": [
            {
              "regexp": ".",
              "file": 1,
              "line": 1,
              "column": 1,
              "message": 1
            }
          ],
          "background": {
            "activeOnStart": true,
            "beginsPattern": { "regexp": "." },
            "endsPattern": { "regexp": "." }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

There have been a number of problems with this approach:

- The `npm run start:v3:background` script still opens a browser some of the time. I am unclear as to why the `BROWSER=none` is ignored.
- Despite trying out different `problemMatchers` the background task doesn't reliably finish. Once it starts opening the browser (of the previous point) it never finishes.
- Stopping the server after it starts seems difficult the approaches I have tried are either platform specific (OSX) or rely on executing VSCode functionality that does not work.

**Question**
Is there any way of making this work? Or should I go the route of attaching? I feel there are some other downsides with that approach most notably that Chrome/Brave/Edge needs to be opened with `--remote-debugging-port`, which from what I can tell isn't easily done by default (i.e. to have Chrome always open with a debugging port) on OSX.

Eiter way I am at a complete loss as to how to make this work reliably. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After finicking around with ChatGPT and some more blogposts, I finally managed to get something working reliably. The `launch.json` is largely unchanged, but I did add a `postDebugTask`.

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000/",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "preLaunchTask": "start server",
      "postDebugTask": "stop server"
    }
  ]
}
```

These are the changes that I made in the `tasks.json`:

- I moved the `BROWSER=none` environment variable to the `tasks.json`. This seems to work consistently, resulting in no additional browser window being opened and preLaunchTask now is considered finished, and no longer blocks the rest of the execution.
- I changed the `beginsPattern` and `endsPattern` of the problem matcher based on [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65431690/how-to-run-and-debug-a-react-app-directly-from-vscode) so that the browser is only launched after the `preLaunchTask` is finished.
- Added a `stop server` script based on [this blogpost](https://christianheilmann.com/2022/03/17/automatically-starting-a-server-when-starting-a-debug-session-in-vs-code/) to close the terminal running the server after the debugging has been stopped.

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "start server",
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "start:v3",
      "group": {
        "kind": "test",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "isBackground": true,
      "options": {
        "env": {
          // Ensures that react-scripts does not open a browser.
          "BROWSER": "none"
        }
      },
      "problemMatcher": {
        "pattern": {
          // This is not needed but, required by the problemMatcher Object
          "regexp": "^$"
        },
        "background": {
          "activeOnStart": true,
          "beginsPattern": "Compiling...",
          // Ensures that browser is only opened after the task is completed.
          "endsPattern": "Compiled .*"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "stop server",
      "command": "echo ${input:terminate}",
      "type": "shell"
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "terminate",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "workbench.action.tasks.terminate",
      "args": "terminateAll"
    }
  ]
}
```